# Python Scattergeo increasing scatter size (Type error : Nonetype and int)

Tags: data-visualization

[image: EarthQuakes]
Sup, ive been stuck on this problem since last night , i am trying to increase the scatter plots on
Scattergeo dependent on the magnitude of a earthquake, i keep getting Nonetype error here's the code, when i add size to :

[Scattergeo(lon=lons,lat=lats,size=[5*mag for mag in mags])]

```
import json
from plotly import offline
from plotly.graph_objs import *


with open('all_month.geojson.json',encoding='utf8') as geo :

    file = json.load(geo)

with open('earthquakes','w') as eq :

    json.dump(file,eq,indent=4)


file = file['features']

mags,lons,lats = [],[],[]


for columns in file :

    mag = columns['properties']['mag']
    lon = columns['geometry']['coordinates'][0]
    lat = columns['geometry']['coordinates'][1]

    mags.append(mag)
    lons.append(lon)
    lats.append(lat)


data = [Scattergeo(lon=lons,lat=lats)]

my_layout = Layout(title='Earthquakes around the world for the past 30 days')


offline.plot({'data':data,'layout':my_layout},filename='Eq.html')
```

Answer (score -1):

OK, i figured it out, when i downloaded the data, there were mutiple options as to the format and i recommend downloading the +1 magnitude and above
.
here is the output[image: Earthquake]